# How can I correctly discover and print the browser window width using JQuery? Why it can't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty new in JQuery and I have the following problem.

My page have to be differently rendered if the browser have specific width (I need it to fix an issue on mobile devices that have a smaller screen)

So as first step I am trying to discover the browser window width (so if it is less to a specific value I consider that the page is showed into a smartphone and I fix my issue).

So I am trying to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    alert(windowWidth);
}
```

I am trying into JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/ayjq1ke0/)

But it seems don't work because I don't see any output. Why? What is wrong? How can I correctly discover and print the browser windows width?

Comment: Just a suggestion, have you looked at CSS's media queries? They are ideal for rendering HTML for different screen sizes, among other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing `jquery` also add this in your `head` tag.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

You are missing `)` add it at end of your code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    alert(windowWidth);
});
```

Fiddle:[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/ayjq1ke0/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Hello AndreaNobili I have updated yourjsFiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/ayjq1ke0/1/

Basically you didn't click your document ready function.

you just needed `);` at the end of your code for it to work :) oohh Also in jsFiddle you need to select what plugin to load, on your jsFiddle you didn't have jQuery selected, so I have added it for ya